# Getting filename from BufferedImage

Tags: java, filenames, bufferedimage

Is there a way to get the filename from a BufferedImage? I don't seem to see any methods for it.

Answer (score 5):

A BufferedImage doesn't necessarily have to be backed by a file.  It could be a byte array in a database, or even backed by a stream.

Answer (score 4):

A `BufferedImage` is not necessarily associated with a file. Just as you can read a String from a file, but there is no `getFilename()` method on String objects, there is no such method on `BufferedImage`.