# Referencing a bufferedImage on a jLabel within a .jar file

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I created a `.jar` file from Eclipse for a project.

Before the `.jar` creation, I was reading in images like this:

```
jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/someImage.png"));
```

But now, for the `.jar`, I'm using:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("someImage.png"));
jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
```

Which works fine, however further in the code, I need to pick between particular images, and the non-.jar file used this:

```
icon = jLabel.getIcon().toString();
if (icon.contains("happy")) {
// do something
```

But obviously this won't work. The `icon` as is comes out just as something like `javax.swing.ImageIcon@35083305`

I tried just adding something like `jLabel.setText("someText");` but I have been unable to retrieve said text.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611303/getting-filename-from-bufferedimage), and note that `BufferedImage` doesn't have a method to get its filename (as of course it may not be a file).

Is there a way I can reference the `jLabel` in a similar fashion?

Comment: *"if (icon.contains("happy")) {"* Put the images in a `Map`, the images being the data and the 'label' or file name being the key. But this really screams model to me, the entire logic would be better encompassed in some sort of (custom, presumably) model that represents the 'state' of the application, Then the 'view' aspect of the MVC can be altered to represent changes to the model.

Comment: `jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/someImage.png"));` - And you program still works when executed directly from the Jar - I'd be surprised

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks I could try a `Map`, but you're probably right with regards to the structure. It's a working program in an IDE, I just wanted to export to a `.jar` to run it that way.

Comment: @MadProgrammer no, that's the way it works in an IDE; I used `BufferedImage` for the `.jar`.